# Magento 1.7 OnepageCheckout SaveBilling returns 200 -> nothing happens

Tags: magento-1.7, onepage-checkout, login, form-key

When I click on the continue button inside the billing section, the tiny loading icon appears and a request is triggered. It returns 200 with an empty response. But then... `nothing happens and there are no errors in the developer console and in the var folder`.

Before there where some issues with the `login` and `forgotten formKeys` by the main-developer.

- Enable Form Key Validation On Checkout is enabled.
- PHP Version 5.4.45

I'm not experienced with magento. I hope someone could help me out.

Is it just a js issue?

Comment: Have you checked with Disable `Enable Form Key Validation On Checkout is enabled.` ?

Comment: Yes sir. Same behaviour with disabled.

Comment: Have you tried with default theme ?

Comment: Yes. Default theme is the same. The difficulty is that I'm not the author of the codebase and the old developer is not reachable anymore.

Comment: Hmm... I checked the saveBilling() function and it seems that it's not executed. Maybe that's the problem?

Comment: You need to know issue is causing due to `theme`, `module`,`admin configuration` or from any custom code